# RecyclerView не находит не погруженный элемент

Tags: android, recyclerview

Я использую в своём приложении Shared Element Transition с ViewPager.

При выходе из ViewPager я должен сопоставить позицию списка ViewPager с позицией RecyclerView.

Собственно мне нужно найти этот элемент в RecyclerView.

Но вот проблема в том, что если этот элемент не виден, то я не могу найти этот скрытый элемент в списке. Мне возвращает Null.

Как найти View элемента списка, если он не прогружен ещё в RecyclerView?

Answer (score 0):

Никак нельзя. View существует только у того, что показывается, готовиться показываться или только что было показано. Если в вашем списке 100 тыс значений, генерировать View для всех - расточительно, поэтому-то они и генерируются только для N отображаемых. Можно увеличить кол-во хранимых в кеше item (потенциальных View), но это путь в никуда. Вам нужно переписать адаптеры и логику, для работы не с View, а с позицией в RecyclerView

Comment: Либо стать на позицию этого элемента в списке.